# New image assets not displayed on Heroku staging site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku, asset-pipeline

**UPDATE:** I have just discovered that only when I push to production do my assets appear on staging.

Whenever I add new image assets, precompile them, and deploy to staging they do not appear. However, everything works locally and on Production. Here is my code and my process whenever adding new image assets. Any help would be appreciated. I am very new to this and have been searching everywhere for an answer.

**staging.rb**

```
Rails.application.configure do
  config.cache_classes = true
  config.eager_load = true
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'http://site_name.herokuapp.com' }
  config.serve_static_files = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  config.assets.compile = false
  config.assets.digest = true
  config.log_level = :debug
  config.action_controller.asset_host = Proc.new { |source|
    if source =~ /\b(.png|.jpg|.gif|.svg)\b/i
      "http://key.cloudfront.net"
    end
  }
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
end
```

**How I precompile my assets for staging**

```
RAILS_ENV=staging bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

**How I precompile my assets for production**

```
RAILS_ENV=staging bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

**application.rb**

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module InfoSite
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those     specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in   config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active   Record auto-convert to this zone.
    # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone   names. Default is UTC.
    # config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'

    config.serve_static_files = true
    config.assets.compile = true
    config.assets.configure do |env|
      if Rails.env.development? || Rails.env.test?
        env.cache = ActiveSupport::Cache.lookup_store(:memory_store)
      end
  end
    # The default locale is :en and all translations from     config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
    # config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*. {rb,yml}').to_s]
    # config.i18n.default_locale = :de

    # Do not swallow errors in after_commit/after_rollback callbacks.
    config.active_record.raise_in_transactional_callbacks = true
  end
end
```

My Process for adding an image asset:

1. Place image in app/assets/images
2. Use it in a layout (using asset pipline: = image_tag 'image.png')
3. Check locally (everything works)
4. Use `RAILS_ENV=staging bundle exec rake assets:precompile`
5. Use `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile`
6. Check github, all assets are updated and I can see that they have     precompiled
7. git push staging master

Now if I view staging, the assets return me an empty image box displaying the image's name.

Is there something I am missing in my process? Should I be taking a different approach to this?

Answer (score 0):

Go to config/application.rb.
Find string `config.assets.enabled` and set value to 'true'.
Or `config.assets.initialize_on_precompile` and set to true.

Comment: I tried both of these methods and my assets are still not loading. I even tried deleting my public/assets folder and precompiling again. I noticed that my new assets were being precompiled but not served. Does this have to do with the method you provided me? I appreciate the help

Comment: Yes I tried both of the methods you described. Do you need any other information that might help from me?

Comment: Try config.assets.compile set to true.

Comment: which rails version is used?

Comment: No luck with that. I am using rails 4.2.1. I have added my application.rb to my question, I hope that helps

Comment: Yes I have read that. Can you please take a look at my recent update? I appreciate the help